# The below code deletes fields in some rows that don't match the if condition. Can anyone check?

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php  for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $ap = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_start_date',true);
        $startdate = date("Ymd", strtotime($ap));
        $todaydate = date("Ymd");
      if(strtotime($todaydate) > strtotime($startdate) && !empty($ap)){
       $del_data = array(
                    'Ref' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_ref',
                    'Start date' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_start_date',
                    'End Date' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_end_date',
                    'Venue' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_venue',
                    'Fees' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_fees',
                    'CPE Credits' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_cpe_credits'
        );
      delete_row('sub_seminars', 1);
    }
   } ?>
```

This code deletes some of the rows of ACF Repeater field in some posts where the `startdate` is not less than the `todaydate`. In some posts it works fine but in some posts it deletes the good rows also. Please can someone tell me what i am doing wrong. See the screenshot http://prnt.sc/eojsz1

Comment: to help us understand and replicate the issue can you provide some `$ap` samples that work and some that don't work as expected?

Comment: I solved the problem. Turns out the forloop was not executing well.

Comment: Solving your problem is just the first step to providing useful information on SO.  It appears that you only removed the for loop to perform the process on the first `$ap`, this seems like more of a workaround than a solution but I don't dabble in WP.  Please expand on your question and answer to better explain how you discovered this problem  and why your solution is suitable.  Now that your question is solved, please award your answer the green tick so that future SO readers don't try to solve an already solved question.  If someone else comes along with a better solution, switch the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF this helps anyone. This worked for me

```
$ap = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_0_start_date',true);
        $startdate = date("Ymd", strtotime($ap));
        $todaydate = date("Ymd");
      if(strtotime($todaydate) > strtotime($startdate) && !empty($ap)){
       $del_data = array(
                    'Ref' => 'sub_seminars_0_ref',
                    'Start date' => 'sub_seminars_0_start_date',
                    'End Date' => 'sub_seminars_0_end_date',
                    'Venue' => 'sub_seminars_0_venue',
                    'Fees' => 'sub_seminars_0_fees',
                    'CPE Credits' => 'sub_seminars_0_cpe_credits'
        );
      delete_row('sub_seminars', 1);
    }
```

Thanks